# Which Linux driver should I download for my AMD Radeon R6?

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, download, amd-radeon

I have a Dell laptop with a AMD Radeon R6 graphics card.

The download's site for AMD drivers (http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) let's you either automatically detect and download the correct driver (only works in Windows), or download them manually.

I've tried finding the correct driver for my laptop by selecting, in the manual download section:

**Step 1**: Notebook graphics

But in **Step 2** I get lost because there are Radeon R5, R7, and R9, but no R6.

I booted up Windows 10 and installed the automatic download tool. It downloaded the file:

```
radeon-crimson-15.12-win10-64bit.exe
```

Which driver should I download for my Ubuntu 64 bit system?

Comment: The definitive guide(https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD) on AMD drivers on ubuntu. Note that as of 16.04 the fglrx binary driver from AMD has been deprecated.

Comment: Thank you Tejas. I'm using Ubutnu 16.04 (Xubuntu actually), so those instructions would appear to not work anymore?

Comment: On Ubuntu can't you just open Driver Manager a different select the suggested driver and install it?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know what that is installing  (it only says 'amd64-microcode') and the behavior of the system is notifiable inferior (in particular the battery life) compared to that I get in Windows 10.

Comment: AMDGPU driver is enabled out of the box for 16.04. You should not need to install anything. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

Comment: Are you talking about the open-source driver? I want to install another one since the performance with that one is visibly below what I see in Windows 10.